# How to setup Azure CosmosDB trigger in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, triggers, azure-cosmosdb

I want to listen to any document update event on my cosmosDB collection, and get the updated document.

I came to know that I can use triggers to accomplish this. But couldn't find a way set this up. 
I believe I can use `client.createTriggerAsync` to register my trigger.
But what are correct trigger JSON entries required for this?
It will be great if someone an share sample JSON to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, cosmos db trigger has `CREATE`,`DELETE` AND `REPLACE` type.However,Triggers in cosmos db are not automatically triggered. Rather, you have to explicitly specify the trigger in the operation that you want to activate the trigger.

According to your situation, I strongly recommand you using [Cosmos DB Trigger Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function) ,please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb). It will listen to any documents update event on your cosmos db collection and trigger the function. You could catch the updated document and return it.

---

Just for summary, we could use polling with `etag` to find out updated documents as workaround.

Comment: Can the same be achieved using a webhook? I already have  a Node app and I can expose an endpoint which can listen to change events. is that possible?

Comment: @Sandy You mean you already have such monitor mechanism in your node app? how you listen to the change events? I think azure function cosmos db trigger is perfect for your scenario,it will automatic triggered if any events on your document db.

Comment: @Sandy Of course,  azure function has http trigger,maybe it's the webhook you mentioned. You could access http trigger to invoke your exposed endpoint in schedule.

Comment: No I dont have any mechanism yet, but what I want is that if Azure Function can be called on DB updates, is it possible to just have a webhook called for DB updates? And that webhook can be an endpoint in my Node App.

Comment: @Sandy Sorry for the misunderstanding.We could chat here:https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181922/jay-and-sandy

Comment: @Sandy As I know, it's impossible to have a webhook which can be called automaticlly for DB updates event.

Comment: ok Thanks Jay. I am currently using polling with etag to find out updated documents. Its only solution for me right now

Comment: @Sandy ok,thanks for your sharing.I summarized your solution in my answer,if you don't mind ,you could mark it for answer for others' reference on the forum,thanks.

Comment: @Sandy I summarized your solution in my answer,if you don't mind ,you could mark it for answer for others' reference on the forum,thanks.